# Given a Parity-check matrix, find all elements in $C$, correct a word and count all words that can not be corrected.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I have this question that I need to solve.
The Parity-Check matrix $H=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&0&1&1&0&1\\0&1&1&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ solves 1 error in code $C$.
a) Find all element in $C$.
b) Correct the word \begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}
c) How many words can not be corrected?

Solutions:
a) $H=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&0&1&1&0&1\\0&1&1&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$~$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&1&1\\0&1&0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$
This gives: $x_1=x_5+x_6$, $x_2=x_4+x_6$ and $x_3=x_4+x_5$.
Possible combinations of $x_4, x_5, x_6$:
$(0,0,0)$ $\implies$ $c1=(000000)$
$(1,0,0)$ $\implies$ $c2=(011100)$
$(0,1,0)$ $\implies$ $c3=(101010)$
$(0,0,1)$ $\implies$ $c4=(110001)$
$(1,1,0)$ $\implies$ $c5=(110110)$
$(0,1,1)$ $\implies$ $c6=(011011)$
$(1,0,1)$ $\implies$ $c7=(101101)$
$(1,1,1)$ $\implies$ $c8=(000111)$

b) Correcting the word \begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix} gives $c6=(011011)$.

c) Can someone please help me here, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: What have you covered so far in your study of parity codes?  Do you understand the relation between $H$ and the matrix to its right in the solutions?

Comment: Are you talking about $H=[-P´|I_{n-k}]$ and $G=[I_k|P]$?

Comment: Yes, that's what happens.  It's Gaussian elimination at work.  The code words are the solutions to the system of linear equations (mod 2) defined by $H$, and you solve them by Gaussian elimination.

Comment: And that tells me what so I can solve c)?

Comment: Once you have identified the so-called information digits, you run through all their combinations (8 in this case), plug them into the equations to compute the parity bits, and you have the code.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that your question is about part c).  Hold on a sec.

Comment: There are 7 error words (besides the codeword 000000) that give a 0 corrector. Those cannot be corrected because they transform a code word into another code word.

Comment: Wait what? How did you come up with 7 (or possibly 8) error words?

Comment: The coset of 000000 consists of 8 6-bit words.  The set of codewords is a subgroup $S$ of order 8 of the group of order 64 of the 6-bit words.  Hence the cosets of $S$ have size 64/8=8.  The coset of 000000 is $S$ itself.